# Nullable value in query

Tags: linq-to-sql, nullable

I need get all items these have no categories

```
int? categoryId = null;
var items=db.Items.Where(x=>x.CategoryId==categoryId);
```

This code generate in where:

```
where CategoryId=null
```

Instead of

```
where CategoryId is null
```

Ok, when I write

```
var items=db.Items.Where(x=>x.CategoryId==null);
```

In my sql profiler it works:

```
where CategoryId is null
```

But when I do this hack it doesn't work:

```
var items=db.Items.Where(x=>x.CategoryId==(categoryId.HasValue ? categoryId : null));
```

So what's the problem? Is there by in L2S?

Update: if categoryId has value it need return something like this:

```
where CategoryId = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try:

```
var items = db.Items.Where( x => !x.CategoryId.HasValue );
```

The problem with the first sample is that LINQ doesn't look at the value of the variable when building the expression.  It just sees and equality expression and converts it into the equivalent expression in SQL. LINQ requires the developer to know and understand how it works with respect to checking for null values.  I think what I've given you is the simplest way to do it.

**Edit**: based on your comment.  You might construct alternate queries if you're looking for matches to categoryId or a null category id if categoryId has no value.  This would be one way of chaining many potential queries together -- and potentially ignoring some comparisions you don't care about in certain situation.

```
IQueryable<Item> items = db.Items;
if (categoryId.HasValue)
{
    items = items.Where( x => x.CategoryId == categoryId );
}
else
{
    items = items.Where( x => !x.CategoryId.HasValue );
}
```

Alternatively (for your simple case), using `object.Equals` seems to compell the LINQ to SQL expression builder to implement IS NULL when the value is null.

```
var item = db.Items.Where( x => object.Equals( x.CategoryId, categoryId ) );
```

Comment: i need when categoryId has value it will return where categoryId=value if not categoryId is null

Comment: that's what i did, but in my case i have 10 values, so for this query i have a lot of code :(
thank u for the fast response

Comment: You might consider using a PredicateBuilder (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)  to build up a complex query instead of chaining them together.  The production of the query could also be refactored into one or more other methods.

Comment: I did a bit of experimenting and came up with a better solution. I'll update.